# Integrate square root of quotient polynomials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to estimate this integral:

$$\displaystyle\int_a^\lambda \sqrt{\frac{(z-a)(z-b)}{z(z-1)}}dz$$

where $a$ and $b$ are closed to 1/2, and $z$ is complex.

Mathematica does not know how to do that. Any idea or reference ?

Comment: Mathematica 10.2 did the implicit integration for me. Its is completely disgusting (uses 4 elliptic integrals after FullSimplify). What version Mathematica were you using?

Comment: I use 9.0.1.0. I'm not necessarily interested on the resulting function, but I need to estimate qualitatively the shape of the real part of the resulting function. Do you think Mathematica 10.2 can do this ?

Comment: I could do: Integrate[Sqrt[(z - a) (z - b)/(z (z - 1))], z] which isn't exactly what you had asked. Trying the integral with definite limits fails on my system but I figured you might be able to substitute in after the implicit integral manually.

Comment: Also I was a bit confused by your statement that $z$ is complex where it is the variable of your integration between two limits. For a complex integral don't you want to have a contour there if its complex?

Comment: Oh, it also works on my version, I didn't notice. I hope i'll be able to draw the curve numerically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Comment: I am also really confused about that. I need to solve this equation extracted from an article: "Stokes curves are the curves on the complex-$\lambda$ plane, which are described by the following equation: $\text{Re} \int_{a}^\lambda {l(z)dz}=0$ " where l(z) is the function I mentioned. For me, we have to specify a path of integration, but I have no information about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked but using Mathematica 10.2 with the input:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Sqrt[(z - a) (z - b)/(z (z - 1))], z]]
```

I got the following output:

$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{(-a+z)(-b+z)}{(-1+z)z}}\left((a-b)(b-z)\sqrt{\frac{(-1+b)(a-z)}{(a-b)(-1+z)}}z\sqrt{\frac{b-z}{b-bz}}+(a-b)b\sqrt{\frac{(-1+a)(b-z)}{(-a+b)(-1+z)}}(-1+z)\sqrt{-\frac{(-1+b)(b-z)z}{b^2(-1+z)^2}}\text{EllipticE}\left[\text{ArcSin}\left[\sqrt{\frac{(-1+a)(b-z)}{(-a+b)(-1+z)}}\right],\frac{a-b}{(-1+a)b}\right]-(-1+b)\left((a-b)\sqrt{\frac{(-1+a)(b-z)}{(-a+b)(-1+z)}}(-1+z)\sqrt{-\frac{(-1+b)(b-z)z}{b^2(-1+z)^2}}\text{EllipticF}\left[\text{ArcSin}\left[\sqrt{\frac{(-1+a)(b-z)}{(-a+b)(-1 + z)}}\right],\frac{a-b}{(-1+a)b}\right]+2(-1+a)(b-z)\sqrt{\frac{(-1+b)z}{b(-1+z)}}\text{EllipticF}\left[\text{ArcSin}\left[\sqrt{\frac{b-z}{b-bz}}\right],\frac{(-1+a)b}{a-b}\right]+b(-1+a+b)(-1+z)\sqrt{-\frac{(-1+b)(b-z)z}{b^2(-1+z)^2}}\sqrt{\frac{b-z}{b-bz}}\text{EllipticPi}\left[b,\text{ArcSin}\left[\sqrt{\frac{b-z}{b-bz}}\right],\frac{(-1+a)b}{a-b}\right]\right)\right)\right)\bigg/\left((a-b)(b-z)\sqrt{\frac{(-1+b)(a-z)}{(a-b)(-1+z)}}\sqrt{\frac{b-z}{b-bz}}\right)$$

You could hopefully then manually apply your limits of integration.

Comment: Jesus Christ...

Comment: I finally found how to solve my problem without using this, but thanks for your help! I just tried Integrate[Sqrt[(z - a) (z - b)/(z (z - 1))], {z,0.1,z}], and it didn't work.